# Two ways of (kind of) instantiating a trait in Scala

Tags: scala, anonymous-class, traits

I know of two ways of making an anonymous class to instantiate a trait in Scala:

```
scala> trait SomeTrait {
     |   def aUsefulMethod = ()
     | }
defined trait SomeTrait

scala> val instance1 = new SomeTrait{} // Method 1
instance1: SomeTrait = $anon$1@7307556f

scala> instance1.aUsefulMethod // Returns a Unit.

scala> object instance2 extends SomeTrait // Method 2
defined module instance2

scala> instance2.aUsefulMethod // Returns a Unit.
```

I can't think of a reason why they are not equivalent. Am I wrong?

I'm asking in part because I used to only know method 2 but now I see that method 1 is more common. So I'm wondering if I've been doing something wrong this whole time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`val instance1 = new SomeTrait{}` is the same as

```
class X extends SomeTrait
val instance1: SomeTrait = new X
```

except the compiler creates the `class X` and gives it a name like `$anon$1`. If you then do `val instance2 = new SomeTrait{}` the compiler will notice it can reuse the same anonymous class. And `object instance2` is also basically

```
class instance2$ extends SomeTrait {
  override def toString = "instance2"
}
lazy val instance2 = new instance2$
```

except you can't create new instances of `instance2$`. So one difference is lazy instantiation: `instance2` is only actually created when it's accessed (e.g. when you call `instance2.aUsefulMethod`), which makes a difference if the `SomeTrait` constructor throws an exception or has other side effects. Another is that you can use `object` at the top level (outside `class`, `trait` or `object`).

Comment: Using `object` at the top level is a clear difference. But it also means that I can use use a singleton anywhere I can use anonymous class instantiation. For the constructor that throws an exception, that's more puzzling to me: isn't it true that, by definition, traits can't *have* a constructor? The only constructor you'd use for any of those examples is the empty, default, constructor.

Comment: No, traits can't have constructor _parameters_. So they can only have the default constructor, but it doesn't have to be empty. It consists of all non-definitions and `val`/`var` initializations in the body, same as for classes. E.g. you can have `trait SomeTrait { throw new Exception }`.

Answer (score 5):

The first approach `new Trait {}` creates a new `class`-instance.

The second approach creates an `object` which is a Singleton.

One can see this in the REPL:

## Define Trait

```
scala> trait Example {}
defined trait Example
```

## New anonymous class

Each call to new will return a new Instance. One can see this that each object gets a new address.

```
scala> new Example{}
res0: Example = $anon$1@768debd

scala> new Example{}
res1: Example = $anon$1@546a03af
```

## Object extending Trait

Here a singleton object is created once.

```
scala> object X extends Example
defined object X

scala> X
res2: X.type = X$@1810399e

scala> X
res3: X.type = X$@1810399e
```

## Impact and comparison

Even if both approaches on the surface may seem similar they lead to different results.

```
scala> new Example{} == new Example{}
<console>:12: warning: comparing values of types Example and Example using `==' will always yield false
   new Example{} == new Example{}
                 ^
 res4: Boolean = false

 scala> X == X
 res5: Boolean = true
```

## Going even deeper

On the underlying structure both aproaches will lead to different `*class` files being generated when run on the `JVM`

### Anonymous class

```
    $ cat example.scala 
    object Example1 {
      trait A
      new A {}
    }

    $ scalac example.scala 

    $ ls *class

      Example1$$anon$1.class Example1$A.class
      Example1$.class        Example1.class         

    $ cat example2.scala 
    object Example2 {
      trait A

      object X extends A
    }

    $ scalac example2.scala 

    $ ls *class
    Example2$.class   Example2$X$.class
    Example2$A.class  Example2.class
```

Comment: I get it. And you can't have anonymous objects the way you have anonymous instances above. But if you make two objects that each extended `Example`, they two would not return `false` when compared using `==`.

I never thought they were the same, but my impression is that, once instantiated, they can be used in identical ways.

Comment: If you create two objects extending the trait they would be in fact different. I added some information on the way how both approaches would affect how the data is translated to the JVM.

Comment: Btw, `val a = new A{}; a == a` works, so it's more like a matter of preference if you're looking for equality. Besides all of that, object might be defined in the root of your *.scala module, value cannot, and object is lazy by default.